# Best tool for sanding and shaping irregular surfaces

Tags: hand-tools, sander

I am looking for some recommendations on sanding irregular surfaces, like rifle stocks.

I have tried a random orbital sander but it is not giving me satisfactory results, and also it is difficult to handle the orbital sander on this type of structure.

This is what I'm working on:

[image: Rifle stock]

[image: Inside of rifle stock]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Unless you don't sand at all, I think the standard recommendation here *would* be a random-orbit sander (with a soft pad backing the paper). But "elliptical surface" is ambiguous in English, I think we need a photograph or at least a sketch to be sure we know what you're working on (as well as the scale of the job). *"random orbital sander but it is not giving me satisfactory results"* In what way or ways was the surface not satisfactory? It might also be helpful to tell us what wood species you're working on.

Comment: Is this a 2-dimensional ellipse or 3-dimensional? i.e. have you cut the ellipse into the edge of a long board (in which case, something like a drum sander would do the trick), or is it a bowl in an elliptical shape, in which case a ROS _seems_ appropriate for the outside, but hand sanding or card scraping would be appropriate for the inside.

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE! Please [edit] this question and tell us what it is you are trying to sand. A picture can often clarify things a lot.

Comment: @Graphus@freeMan @jdv I have edit my question and add the image exactly what Im trying to sand..thanks in advanced...

Comment: A) You can only "ping" one person per post using `@<username>`. it's OK, we'll probably all find it... B) oof... that's complex! I've never sanded a gun stock before, but my guess is you'll have to do it by hand. You may still find card scrapers useful, but you may also end up with flats doing that - I'd wait until those with more experience chime in. C) That's a nice looking piece of work so far! Keep at it!

Comment: Well that's nothing like what I was imagining! Anyway, I can't tell if this a new stock that you're preparing for first finishing or an old stock that has been stripped. If it's an old stock in particular, but also possibly if it's new, you may want to *exclusively* sand by hand. This is the only way to ensure you sand just enough in each zone and, very important, don't round over edges that should remain sharp (especially around the inletting and where the butt plate/pad will go!) [contd]

Comment: How much have you looked at on prepping rifle stocks? I ask because I know there's tons of good (free) guidance out there on this. Plus, SE values queries where it's obvious research was done but the OP needs clarification on something specific, or has run into an issue that what was read/watched didn't cover.

Comment: thanks @Graphus for your advice. the one in picture is new. we basically custom made for our customers. until last year much of the work was done manually ..but now we are trying to use machines to complete the work faster. I'm still researching on to the topic..and seeking more expert's advices.

Comment: Some advice. Do as much as you can to produce the smoothest surface possible straight from the shaping operation; the extra time the final machining pass takes will more than offset the labour and time manually smoothing afterwards. *Don't start sanding too fine;* this is the commonest error in sanding, because nobody wants to put those coarse scratches into the wood and then have to erase them with further sanding, but removing lots of wood requires coarse grit (80 grit at least, but 60 grit or below may be advisable). *Work up in the progression of grits in measured stages** [contd]

Comment: ...so if you start at 80 next grit is 120, then 180, then 240 and finally 320 **if** you go that far (it's most common in woodworking to only sand up to about 180-240 grit but for rifle stocks intended for an oil finish you may want to sand more finely). *Change paper often*; abrasives are a consumable and should be used until they stop cutting efficiently, then discarded. *Better abrasives are usually worth it*; higher quality sandpapers, sanding cloth or sanding screens last much better than cheaper paper and usually more than offset their higher cost with how much longer they last.

Comment: thank you @Graphus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try a sanding disk on a drill. Similar to what is used to sand wooden bowls, for example [here](https://turnawoodbowl.com/bowl-sanding-tools-and-finish-techniques/).

It looks like the challenge with the orbital sander might be its size, thats why a small sanding disk on a drill might allow you to approach the gunstock on more comfortable angles.

Comment: Could you expand on this some to indicate how this would work and how it would be better than the issues the OP is having with his ROS?

Comment: thank you @NicoTek...Let me try that...

Comment: Based on the recently posted photo of a gun stock, I'm struggling to see how a "sanding disk on a drill" will help. Again, some explanation of the recommended technique would be most helpful. It may be fully explained in the link, but links die. As a user from other SE sites (and with a "mod diamond"), you should know to include relevant bits from the linked site.

Answer (score 2):

For work like this you need a collection of sanding blocks in various shapes, and sanding sponges, possibly cut into custom shapes.

For faster removal this is one of the few situations where small rotary tools like a Dremel will come in handy. Almost certainly you will find all sorts of shaping and sanding attachments suitable for crafting rifle stocks. I suspect a single web search for "dremel gun stock" will yield all sorts of opportunity for parting with your money.

Once you've shaped and sanded down to some level with a rotary tool, then I think you should switch to hand sanding using sponges, and store-bought and hand-made blocks. Again, don't reinvent the wheel here; people have been making weapon stocks out of wood for centuries. See what other people are using, possibly on another SE related to gun-making.

There is absolutely no tool better for gauging fairness and smoothness (all paramount for rifle stocks) than the human eye and hand.

Comment: thanks a lot @jdv